# $\Gamma$-convergence vs. uniform convergence: conditions for convergence of minimizers of functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, pointwise-convergence, variational-analysis

In variational problems, sometimes we want to show that minimizers of a sequence of functionals $F_n$ converge to the minimizers of some $F$. To do this, we usually show 1) $\Gamma$-convergence of $F_n$ to $F$ and 2) compactness.

$\Gamma$-convergence is a weak way to describe the convergence $F_n \rightarrow F$. It involves showing [liminf and limsup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%93-convergence#Definition) inequalities. In addition to $\Gamma$-convergence, a compactness property is needed: namely that if $F_n(u_n) < \infty$ for all $n$, then there is a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ converging to some limit $u$.

However, what if we show strong/uniform convergence of $F_n \rightarrow F$? Do we still need a compactness property? If so, can we use a weaker version? By strong convergence, I mean that $F_n(u_n) \rightarrow F(u)$ for all $n$, and all $u_n \rightarrow u$ (wrt whatever norm the domain uses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot substitute continuous convergence for the compactness condition. Consider the following example.

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\exp(-|x|)$. For each $n = 1, 2, \dots$, let $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
\begin{equation}
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
   f(x) & \text{if $|x| \leq n$,} \\
   [f(n) + f'(n)(|x|-n)]_+ & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $[c]_+ := \max\{0, c\}$. In English, $f_n$ agrees with $f$ on the interval $[-n,n]$, but then linearly interpolates with the line $y=0$. [A Desmos graph is worth a thousand words.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tetml7zxyk)

Let's show that $f_n \to f$ continuously. Let $x_n \to x$. Then there exists $M > 0$ such that $x,x_n \in [-M, M]$ for all $n$. Letting $n_0 \geq M$, it follows that $f_n(x_n) = f(x_n)$ for all $n \geq n_0$; hence, $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$.

On the other hand, $\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{\mathrm{argmin}}$

1. $\argmin f = \emptyset$,
2. $\argmin f_n = \mathbb{R} \setminus [-c,c]$,

where $c = n - f(n)/f'(n)$.

I am not aware of any general condition that can be traded for the compactness criterion, except for a more stringent compactness criterion (e.g., $f, f_n$ share the same compact support).

Comment: could you please explain what the $\Gamma$-limit will be in that case?

Comment: $f$ is the $\Gamma$-limit of $\{f_n\}$.

Comment: Thank you, do you know the example when the (pointwise) limit and $\Gamma$-limit do not coincide?

Comment: Let $f_n(x) = \mathbf{1}\{x \ne 1/n\}$, and observe that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, while the $\Gamma$-limit is $\mathbf{1}\{x \ne 0\}$. ($\mathbf{1}C$ means the characteristic function on the set $C$.) So in general both the pointwise and $\Gamma$ limits may exist without coinciding.

Comment: Thank you! Am I right that in this way the pointwise limit and $\Gamma$-limit will be different at one point. But if we want that they will be different at any point we can construct something like (let us consider interval $[0,1]$ for simplicity) a sequence of the functions where $f_n(x)=\mathbb{1}\{x\neq 1/p\}$, where $p\in\mathbb{P}, \ p\leq n$

Comment: Off hand I don't think it's possible for the pointwise and $\Gamma$ limits to disagree *everywhere* but it certainly can be more than one point. Enumerate the rationals $r_1, r_2, \dots$ and consider $f_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}\{x = r_j\}$. Then $f_n$ converges to $\mathbf{1}\mathbb{Q}$ pointwise but converges to the constant function $f(x)=1$ in the $\Gamma$ sense.

Comment: Thank you, David, good luck with your research!

Comment: Let us take $F_h(x)=0$, if $h(x-e^h)$ is integer and $F_h(x)=1$, otherwise. $F_h\to 0$ in $\Gamma$ sense but $F_h\to 1$ pointwise everywhere